# How to generate and set username in Laravel eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have some fields in user table:

```
id  firstName  lastName userName
```

Here I need to generate and save an userName automatically where the user will provide only firstname & lastName. I have tried something like this but not sure about the piece of code.

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
...

protected $appends = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'userName'];

protected $attributes = ['userName' => 'default'];

 public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub

        self::creating(function ($model) {
            $randNum = rand(10, 99);
            $userName = $model['firstName'] . $model['lastName'] . $randNum;
            $model->userName = $userName;
        });
    }

}
```

So whenever I'm trying to migrate & seed it's showing

> Field 'userName' doesn't have a default value

The seeder is

```
 public function run()
 {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'firstName' => 'Osman',
            'sureName' => 'Rafi',
            'email' => 'rafi.ogchy@gmail.com',
            'password' => Hash::make('password'),
           
        ]);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is [Model events](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events).

First define a static boot method on your model. In there you can then run your username generation code.

```
class User extends Model 
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::creating(function($model){
            $randNum = rand(10, 99);
            $userName = $model['firstName'] . $model['lastName'] . $randNum;
            $model['userName'] = $userName;
        });
    }
}
```

This will intercept the creation of your model, and generate the username.

Comment: it still thowing `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'userName' doesn't have a default value` error

Comment: Set it to a default value. `protected $attributes = [ 'userName' => 'default' ];`

Comment: I'm afraid. still the error is there. Note that I'm trying to run a seed, is it a problem there ?

Comment: Please update your question with the code for your seed as well.

Comment: Please check the question again @Linus

Comment: well, I found the problem, Since I was inserting seed with hard coded values it was throwing the error. adding `nullable` in the field in migration can solve the problem or using the factory to seeder could be another alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

`setUserNameAttributes` function only works when you set username to model, not works automatically

you need to define `setFirstNameAttribute` function and inside it generate your username

Note: last word in function name is Attribute not Attributes*